# Debian not recognizing my ttyS0 / console redirection not working

Tags: grub, console, serial-port, headless, uart

I have a fitlet2 (https://fit-iot.com/web/products/fitlet2/) which has a serial port. I can connect to the serial port of the fitlet2 with screen from my computer (screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200) and access the BIOS, after I have enabled the "Serial Port Console Redirection" in the BIOS.

I am also able to access the GRUB Bootloader over serial. Access over serial works in various GRUB bootloaders (debian/ubuntu installer, debian installed). But whenever the system is loaded, I can no more access the serial port which I was using.

I tried to activate console redirection in GRUB for the system by editing the boot parameters according to this post https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-serial-console-on-debian-linux/. Soon I realized that my ttyS0 is somehow not working correctly. Starting to debug my physical serial interfaces I just couldn't find a way to get this to work.

Setserial tells me the following:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A,  Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A,  Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 5
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A,  Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 7
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

dmesg | grep tty this:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/pen--01--vg-root ro console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0,115200n8
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/pen--01--vg-root ro console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty0,115200n8
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[   49.308213] console [ttyS0] disabled
[   49.312635] dw-apb-uart.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x81424000 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   49.407713] usb 1-8.2: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   49.410489] usb 1-8.2: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   49.411349] usb 1-8.2: Qualcomm USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   53.577143] console [ttyS0] enabled
[   54.744793] dw-apb-uart.1: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x81422000 (irq = 5, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   54.755771] dw-apb-uart.2: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x81420000 (irq = 7, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[  115.902885] ttyS2 - failed to request DMA
```

Why is ttyS0 disabled and again reenabled? How can I enable it/use it properly?

How can I get my login shell on serial? What am I missing?

Comment: To clarify: This is about booting GRUB on the fitlet2, and serial works while GRUB is active, but stops working as soon as GRUB hands over to the kernel, did I understand that correctly? First step would be to read up on the `dw-apb-uart` module, and see if you can verify its state. Normally 16550A's are port mapped, not memory mapped, and it's possible `setserial` doesn't work for memory mapped devices (but better verify this). So you may need some other way to set parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> Soon I realized that my ttyS0 is somehow not working correctly.
> Starting to debug my physical serial interfaces I just couldn't find a
> way to get this to work.

In my case, on a fitlet2 with Atom E3950 cpu, **ttyS2** is the device node that corresponds with the serial port on the back of the machine.
I've been able to use it as a console with the usual `console=ttyS2,115200` kernel command line option. I've tested with the current Debian stable kernel (4.19.152-1) and unstable (5.9.11-1).

When using stable, I also see the `ttyS2 - failed to request DMA` message but it works nevertheless.

On my machine I have:

```
# cat /proc/tty/driver/serial                                         
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:                                                    
0: uart:16550A mmio:0x7FFFF0E000 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0                                
1: uart:16550A mmio:0x7FFFF0C000 irq:5 tx:0 rx:0 CTS                            
2: uart:16550A mmio:0x480000000 irq:6 tx:1067 rx:38 RTS|CTS|DTR                 
3: uart:16550A mmio:0x7FFFF0A000 irq:7 tx:0 rx:0 CTS
```

Try as I may, I was not able to get grub to natively use the serial port. As you say, the grub interface is accessible over the serial port when you enable serial console redirection in the firmware but I believe that's through the agency of the firmware driving the serial port. In that mode, configuring grub with `terminal console` is sufficient to have output on the serial port. Regardless, it works well enough.